# Are shifted squared terms linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I suspect that my intiuition for this is very wrong, but I feel like polynomials of the form $(x-a)^2$ and $(x-b)^2$ should not be linearly independent (since you can relate them by a shift), and yet if you try to find a non-zero $(\lambda, \mu)$ such that $\lambda (x-a)^2 + \mu (x-b)^2 \neq 0$, it is not possible.

I suppose the latter is defining for linear independence, but I cannot but feel uncomfortable with this. I would appreciate if someone had some intuition for linear independence, that would help me feel more comfortable with these polynmoials being linearly independent.

Comment: Two nonzero elements of a vector space are linearly dependent on one another if and only if they are scalar multiples of one another.  Being related "*by a shift*" is completely irrelevant.  These are clearly not scalar multiples of one another and so are independent.

Comment: That said, the original definition is still the best definition to familiarize yourself with... Note that regardless the values of $a,b,c,d$ you would have $\{(x-a)^2, (x-b)^2, (x-c)^2, (x-d)^2\}$ would still form a linearly dependent set since you can indeed find scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ with at least one nonzero such that $\alpha(x-a)^2+\beta(x-b)^2+\gamma(x-c)^2+\delta(x-d)^2=0$ since the polynomials of degree at most $2$ form a $3$-dimensional vector space (*with basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ as an example*).  This, despite none of these being a scalar multiple of any other.